# Xamarin Forms iOS app crashing on start up suddenly

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms iOS app was working fine. Suddenly it started crashing on launch of the app. The debug point is not even hitting app delegate or app.xaml.cs. I tried changing few iOS configs. I tried removing all packages and added them back to check. Also, I check both in simulator and device. Also, in iPad and iPhone versions.

The same code is working for Android. Can you please guide me how to go about this scenario and how to figure out where the problem is?

Is it possible to stop working suddenly like this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your bin+obj folders of both the iOS and the core project and doing a complete rebuild? In my experience there are often strange things with Xamarin that are solved by completely rebuilding

Comment: Try to changed the device or  cleared simulator contents.

Comment: i have a same issue after upgrading xcode to 10.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in Main.cs, line of AppDelegate reference got commented out somehow. That is the reason for the crash.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using  exception handling? it's really usefull in this situation.

```
    try ()
{
//your code
}
catch(exception e)
{
Messagebox.Show(e);
}
```

Comment: And you are using WinForm's Messagebox.Show for Xamarin.Forms?